# Trying to skip over objects that are in an array when filtering

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am trying to maintain objects that are "active" ie stored in global state when a filter is applied (currently the disappear when the filter is set). To do this I am trying to get the array of objects from state with a selector and then skip over any of the objects in that array where there is a matching id when filtering occurs. Unfortunately this is not working:

```
  const activeCards = selectors.getActiveCards();


 {selected === "Morphology"
          ? // Filters through the 'morphemeData' array
            morphemeData
              .filter(
                (m: Affix) =>
                  // Returns items from the array where either no search term is present or the start of the affix name matches the search term (case insensitive)
                  (!searchTerm ||
                    m.affix_name
                      .toLowerCase()
                      .startsWith(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) &&
                  (filter === "all" ||
                    (m.affix_position === filter &&
                      !activeCards.morphemes.some(
                        (activeCard) => activeCard.id === m.id
                      )))
              )
              .map((m: Affix) => (
                <MorphemeCard
                  key={m.id}
                  morpheme={m}
                  position={selectors.getMorphemePosition(m)}
                  onMoved={(position) => actions.setMorpheme(m, position)}
                  onReset={() => actions.resetMorpheme(m)}
                />
              ))
```

Here's how the activeCards data looks

```
morphemes:[
{id: 6, affix_name: 'es', affix_position: 'suffix', affix_description: 'Th -es suffix means there is more than one (plural)', affix_example: 'The buses are all running late', …},
{id: 8, affix_name: 'ade', affix_position: 'suffix', affix_description: 'The suffix -ade is used to indicate a fruit (often citrus) flavoured drink.', affix_example: 'This lemonade is delicious', …},
{id: 9, affix_name: 'age', affix_position: 'suffix', affix_description: 'The suffix -age means a collection of things', affix_example: 'We are taking alot of baggage on our trip.', …}
]
```

Comment: How the `morphemeData` looks?